# Creating Raster to Point data using ArcMap ModelBuilder Iterate raster tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, error-999999, iteration

Creating Raster to Point data using ArcGIS ModelBuilder Iterate raster

1. Raster material is in folder (ffaa)
2. Using Iterate rasters in model builder
3. Select folder 1 (ffaa) in step 2
4. Raster to point function input and input raster, output point feature setting
5. Set field to blank

[image]

**Status**

ArcToolbox's raster to point function creates 1 raster to point data.
However, it fails in ModelBuilder.

As a result of confirmation, there is no field selection in the raster to point of ModelBuilder.
I tried entering a value in the field name, but it failed.

**Error message**

> ERROR 010151: No features found in raster. Possible empty feature
> class. Failed to execute (Raster to Point).
>
> ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (Raster to
> Point).

**desired goal**

When I want to use the raster to point function in the ModelBuilder, I want to select the field I want in the field selection.

So I directly used Value, "", ==, %%, %Value%, !Value!, $Value$, all, && etc in the field field, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Yes. I am using (arcMap10.7, 30 days use).

Comment: My question can be basic.
However, it works when converting one by one using a tool, but does not work when raster to point is performed using the "model builder". As a result of the confirmation, "field" is displayed as blank. This is my first time seeing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check the configuration of the Raster To Point tool in your model.

It looks like you have set Output point features to:

```
D:WexportW%name%.shp
```

instead of:

```
D:\WexportW%name%.shp
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the storage path. In my opinion, it will need to be resolved in the part of loading the raster file or in the field setting part.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer through various attempts.

The file I have is raster.
Do not put this in a folder, just save it in GDB format and run it.

I don't know why this is happening.